# approximate image with multiple connected line segments

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV "fitline()" to approximate thin images to line segments, but in some cases when I deal with a situation like this [image: thin image], I hope to approximate it with multiple connected line segments rather than only one to more accurately reflect curved features. For this example, I hope to get 2 or 3 connected line segments. I tried "approxPolyDP()", but it does not seem to do this job.

Could anyone please give a hint for it?

Comment: there is no single function to do that in OpenCV. OpenCV can extract contours, but it can't extract ridges. nobody has implemented that yet. -- you'd have to *thin* the shape, then walk all its pixels and record points in order (after the thinning, it will be a tree).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitzThank you for the suggestion. It seems I could thin the image with thinning() function in Opencv ximgproc, but I have to implement my own algorithm to get the line segments.

Comment: correction: might be just a tree (or line), but will be a graph in general

Comment: It turns out HoughLinesP() does  a very good job to get approximated line segments with the right parameter settings.